# Is there a real number, that is proven to be normal in every base, whose digits can be enumerated by an algorithm?

Tags: real-analysis, normal-distribution

To clarify, I mean every natural number base $b$ where $b \geq 2$. If so, what is the algorithm to generate the number (and what is the number, if it has a name)?

Answer (score -2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples) reveals that the answer is yes, citing the paper "[An example of a computable absolutely normal number](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975%2801%2900170-0)" by Becher and Figueira (*Theoretical Computer Science* 270(1-2), 2002).

Comment: So... has anyone come up with an example?

Comment: @Izzhov: It's hard to believe you've read that article in the time since I posted that link. But why would you be asking more questions before doing so?

Comment: I don't think you actually have to read the paper. It suffices to examine the title: "An example of a computable absolutely normal number"

Comment: I actually read the Wikipedia article (which doesn't say whether an algorithm exists) before I asked the question; in fact it was what inspired me to ask in the first place! However, I hadn't checked out the paper, hence not knowing that an example had been detailed (since the Wiki article was misleading and implied that the paper only proved that such a number existed, and didn't actually give the algorithm).

Comment: Answers on this site are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: @MJD: If you want to waste your time copying stuff out of a pdf, go ahead.

Comment: I added the name and reference details of the paper so people can still find it if ScienceDirect changes their URLs in the future.

Comment: What is $b_1$ the first bit of the binary expansion of the number provided by Becher and Figueira's algorithm?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Let me be more explicit: I had read B&F's paper before and I saw nowhere in it the value of the first bit $b_1$ of the normal number $b$ (despite the title of their section 3.1...). Hence I find rather odd the claim by the authors (copied on the WP page) that their algorithm indeed "generates" a number $b$. Before declaring that the answer to the OP question is "yes", at least some explanations about the meaning of some words used in B&F seem to be in order.

Comment: @Chris I had exactly the same misgivings.